# Create/rename a file/folder that begins with a dot

Tags: file-management, files

I have created an advanced `settings.xml` file for Kodi on my Samsung tablet and need to create a directory called `/.kodi/userdata` to put it in. Everytime I try to create it, it says invalid entry.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a different file manager app, such as [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop).

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that you are trying to do this using the tablet.

I bet that there is an easier way to do this but, as a workaround, I would just create it using my computer. If there is no easy way to access the destination folder on computer, maybe a file explorer could do the final moving for you from a storage device of your tablet.